# Better to use CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) or view.bounds.size.height directly in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-2d, cgrect

I can't find where I read it, but I remember coming across something that suggested it is better to access height of `CGRect`s using `CGRectGetHeight(rect)` instead of accessing the variable via `rect.size.height`

```
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.frame);
// vs  
CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height;
```

Most of the time, this has to do with views in my use, and I was wondering if there is a real difference (apart from syntax) that separates these two lines of code.

If one is preferential over the other, an explanation of why would be great!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

CGRect structures might store height and width in negative values and `CGRectGetHeight` will always return the positive one. In Swift 3.0 `CGRect.height` property should be used instead of `CGRectGetHeight`.

[CGRect.height](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect/1455645-height)

> Regardless of whether the height is stored in the CGRect data
>   structure as a positive or negative number, this function returns the
>   height as if the rectangle were standardized. That is, the result is
>   never a negative number.

Comment: That was it, I couldn't remember why it said! Thanks! I'll accept in 10 mins. (when it lets me)

Comment: More generically, from the [CGGeometry reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html): “All functions described in this reference that take `CGRect` data structures as inputs implicitly standardize those rectangles before calculating their results. For this reason, your applications should avoid directly reading and writing the data stored in the `CGRect` data structure. Instead, use the functions described here to manipulate rectangles and to retrieve their characteristics.”

Comment: In Xcode 8.2.1 using `CGRectGetHeight` results in a compliation error: “_CGRectGetHeight' has been replaced by property ‘CGRect.height’_”.

Comment: CGRectGetHeight in Swift is CGRect.height.
Eg. view.frame.height